# Display reports on mobile device

Tags: mobile, reporting-services

I have a business application which I am going to extend by creating mobile versions of it for the Blackberry and iPhone lines. One of the requirements is for the mobile devices to be able to display reports.

What is the easiest way to do this? Output the report as HTML or something else. Does this also require a crazy amount of scrolling on the device to view things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion you had to think the mobile web differente from web. The operation available from mobile must be the operation the user need to do now, he cannot wait for them. Generally viewing a report can be postpone to be done from Desktop pc.

So suppling a mobile version of a web application involve also the choice of which operation supply and wich don't.

Comment: I agree with your comment. However, I think things just need to change for the mobile environment.

Comment: Yes the mobile environment are changing quickly. Also the tablets are mobile or desktop? They are in the middle, and we had to support them with the same attention we support the other devices. So I suggest you to provide pdf output, the phone can navigate them if they don't fit the screen. I think HTML reports are too complex.